# To display special character in pdf using itextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

How to display character like '&' in pdf.I am using itextsharp to create pdf.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more to work with. What does "no working" mean. Is something else being displayed or is the character just not appearing? Are you parsing HTML or just using regular `Phrase` and `Paragraph` classes? Below is a full sample that uses regular iTextSharp classes as well as the `HTMLWorker` to display ampersands. All three work just fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a new document
            iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER);

            //Write it to a memory stream
            using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                object writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, FS);

                //Open the PDF for writing
                Doc.Open();

                //Insert a page
                Doc.NewPage();

                //Add a phrase with an ampersand
                Doc.Add(new Phrase("Hello & Goodbye"));

                //Create some HTML with an escaped and also unescaped ampersand
                string Html = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><p>This is an escaped ampersand : &amp;</p><p>And this is a non-escaped ampersand : &</body></html";

                //Read the HTML in a StringRead
                using (StringReader SR = new StringReader(Html))
                {
                    //Grab the elements
                    List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(SR, null);

                    //Loop through them
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Add them to the document
                        Doc.Add(elements[i]);
                    }
                }

                //Close the PDF
                Doc.Close();
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```